# Passing variables to a referenced function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currntly have a nameless function in a javascript ajax-call:

(This code has been cut down to the essentials, there might be some errors)

```
function call(name){
    var type = services[name].type


    $.oajax({
        success: function(data) {
            fbposts=data.data
                if (type === "grupp"){
                    var postid=fbposts[fbpost].id.split("_");
                    return "https://www.facebook.com/groups/"+postid[0]+"/permalink/"+postid[1]+'/'
                }
                else if (fbposts[fbpost].actions){
                    return fbposts[fbpost].actions[0].link;
                }
            }
        }       
    })
};
```

I want to insead use

```
success: successfunction,
```

and the reference the function like this:

```
function success(data) {
            fbposts=data.data
                if (type === "grupp"){
                    var postid=fbposts[fbpost].id.split("_");
                    return "https://www.facebook.com/groups/"+postid[0]+"/permalink/"+postid[1]+'/'
                }
                else if (fbposts[fbpost].actions){
                    return fbposts[fbpost].actions[0].link;
                }
            }
        }       
    })
```

At this point, the type-variable is no longer defined. Can I somehow solve this?

Comment: Have you tried passing type as a second variable? so you would have function successfunction(data, type) {...} and then pass type as a parameter from success: successfunction(data, type)

Comment: Where are you defining the function? If you don't need it outside of `call()`, you could try defining it inside that so it shares the same scope as the `type` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that could work is to make use of the `context` parameter on `$.ajax` -- for example:

```
function successFunction(data) {
    fbposts=data.data;
    if (type === "grupp"){
        var postid=fbposts[fbpost].id.split("_");
        return "https://www.facebook.com/groups/"+postid[0]+"/permalink/"+postid[1]+'/'
    }
    else if (fbposts[fbpost].actions){
        return fbposts[fbpost].actions[0].link;
    }
}

function call(name){
    var type = services[name].type;
    $.oajax({
        success: successFunction,
        context: { type: type }
    );
}
```

Using `context` causes `this` inside your `success` function to point to whatever you passed in for `context`. So in the above example, when within `successFunction` we read

```
if (type ...)
```

this would mean that `type` refers to `this.type`, which is the same value of `type` that we saved into `context` from within `call`.

Comment: great! is there a context for the other functions referenced aswell, like beforeSend, error etc?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren: I haven't tested, but the docs say that the context is for "all Ajax-related callbacks".

Comment: It's the same! Although i need to specify this.type not just typem in all callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solve that by defining `success()` inside `call`, so this has the same scope:

```
function call(name){
    var type = services[name].type;
    function success(data) {
                fbposts=data.data
                    if (type === "grupp"){
                        var postid=fbposts[fbpost].id.split("_");
                        return "https://www.facebook.com/groups/"+postid[0]+"/permalink/"+postid[1]+'/'
                    }
                    else if (fbposts[fbpost].actions){
                        return fbposts[fbpost].actions[0].link;
                    }
                }
            }       
        })

    $.oajax({
        success: success   
    })
};
```

Alternate solution is to store it outside, eg. in some outer scope, in some variable, or attached to one of the DOM elements.

You can also use a wrapper, that called with proper type will return success function knowing this type like that:

```
function make_success(type){
    return function(data){
        // do what you need for success callback
    };
}
var my_success_callback = make_success('some_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the success function return the function you need to pass to ajax, and pass the type variable to the parent function - much like a Python decorator. Here's an example:

```
function call(name){
    var type = services[name].type;

    $.ajax({
        success: success(type)
    })
};

function success(type) {
    return function(data) {
        // We have access to 'type' in here!

        fbposts=data.data;
        if (type === "grupp"){
            var postid=fbposts[fbpost].id.split("_");
            return "https://www.facebook.com/groups/"+postid[0]+"/permalink/"+postid[1]+'/'
        }
        else if (fbposts[fbpost].actions){
            return fbposts[fbpost].actions[0].link;
        }
    }
}
```